# How to read values from a properties file located in tomcat conf folder

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm working on Spring MVC application.

I had some older project and I'm trying to follow the same structure. So there is a `properties` file in the tomcat **conf** folder. I have to read the values from it. And my STS is pointing to that tomcat when running (it use the same server)

so I did following changes,

```
// place the below in my Java class
@Value( "${profileImagePath}" )
private String imagePath;
```

and at the bottom of the `servelet-config.xml` I placed the below code,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/app.properties" />
```

There were no errors but when I try to print the value `imagePath` it prints as `null`

what can be the problem here.

Comment: Can you check if you can find some logs in the deployment DEBUG logs which suggest that app.properties was actually loaded? Also, is the class package included under component scanning? The `@Value` annotation is processed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is typically registered if you have a `<component-scan>` or `<annotation-config>` configuration in XML (or directly with a bean definition)

Comment: Hmm. I moved that `@Value` code snippet to a Controller class. And it worked inside that. But can't have it in a normal Java class.

Comment: And is that normal java class annotated and covered with component scan configuration?

Comment: yes. It's a simple java class.